# What's wrong with the MQ supportPac MA01?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I tried using the Q program from MA01 in AIX, but it always show below error. Would you please help me out

```
$ ./q -oTEST -mMB8QMGR
MQSeries Q Program by Paul Clarke [ V6.0.0 Build:May  2 2012 ]
Error loading MQ library  RC(8)
$ dspmq
QMNAME(MB8QMGR)                                           STATUS(Running)
$ dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.10
CMVC level:  p701-110-130419
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying the "library name" as per the manual.
i.e.

```
./q -oTEST -mMB8QMGR -lmqm
```

Comment: yes, but it returned with same error: $ ./q -oTEST -mMB8QMGR -lmqm
MQSeries Q Program by Paul Clarke [ V6.0.0 Build:May  2 2012 ]
Error loading MQ library mqm RC(2)

Comment: You say it returned the same error, but it didn't. Your question text says the load gave RC(8) and your comment says the load gave RC(2). These are return codes from dlopen(). If you're still having this problem we can get Q to print out some debug information too.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be due to loading 64bit libs. See if LIBPATH has `/usr/mqm/lib64`, if it has, then disable it temporarily.

```
export LIBPATH=
```